# Stream files on Window 8 from Mac OS X

Tags: macos, windows-8, file-sharing

My roommates and I got a new tv and we'd like to only have 1 computer connected to it so we can play our media from this laptop. The laptop connected to the tv is Windows 8 and I have no problem access shared files from other windows machines.

However, one of them is using a Mac and I don't want to ask her to move her files over to my shared drive. How do I map her OSX media file to my windows 8 machine so she can just use my computer to access her movies on her laptop?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable file sharing on her Mac - [here are detailed instructions](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1549?viewlocale=en_US)

Than you will connect to that share from your Windows using the SMB protocol the same way you would connect to any other share: \mac\sharename or map a drive using the

> net use

command